# Sets and Notation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

There is a set like:

$V = \{f : R \to R \mid f(x) = ax + c \text{ with } a, c \in \mathbb{R} \}$

I do not know what "$:$" means.
I do not know what "$|$" means.

I think the meaning is something like "is defined as" but i can not find more documentation.

What is the difference between "$:$" and "$|$"?

When do i use the one and when the other?

How would i use them in a spoken sentence?

---

Edit: changed x to V.

Edit: changed example to make more senese in general

Edit: changed example to improve even further.

Comment: I think they are the same.

Comment: But in this case, I am not sure what x is.

Comment: Are you sure that you copied that correctly?  It looks very strange.  Where exactly did you see it?

Comment: usually, $x:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ means a function which maps real numbers to real numbers.

Comment: But if $x$ is such a function, then $x<4$ makes no sense.

Comment: well, sometimes you write $f<a$ to say that $f(t)<a$ for each $t$, so in this sense... it makes sense.

Comment: The "mapping" interpretation of $x:R\to R$ seems to entirely contradict the constraint $x\lt 4$...

Comment: why? I interprete this so: $V=\{x:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\ |\ \forall t\in\mathbb R:x(t)<4\}$

Comment: And now everything has changed. As mentioned in the answer below, $f:R\to R$ is a function which domain $R$ and codomain $R$. After $|$ we give constrains. In this case, each $f$ has to be of the form $f(x)=ax+b$, so $V$ consists of all the (affine) linear functions (and assume that its coefficients $a$ and $b$ are in $R$ as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context.  Here is an example:

Consider both sets $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x < 2 \}$ and $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} | x < 2 \}$.

These sets both represent the **same** set.  The : and | should both be read as "such that".  So you read both sets as "the set of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x < 2$".

---

Now, when we define a function, say, $f: X \to Y$, the : is included after the *name* of the function, in this case $f$, and before the listing of the domain and codomain of the function.  So $f: X \to Y$ is how we start to define a function $f$ with domain (or input) from $X$ and codomain (or output) in $Y$.

The problem is in your example, $\{x : R \to R | x < 4\}$, we are using both : and |.  But the : looks like it is used as defining a function $x$ with domain $R$ and codomain $R$.  Then the | looks like it is a such that.  So, *I* would read this set as "the set of functions $x$ from $R$ to $R$ such that $x < 4$".

Now, does it really make sense to say functions are less than $4$?  No.  We usually say a function's output is less than $4$, so that makes me believe there is something wrong with the set you wrote down.  Is it possible you copied it down wrong?  But from a math language point of view, the set you wrote down **can** be read in plain English, as above.  It just doesn't appear to be a meaningful description.

(Although, there is a debate as many mathematicians use $x < 4$ for a function $x$ as shorthand to say for all inputs, the output is less than $4$, but this notation is rarely used in undergraduate courses, from my experience.)

---

**EDIT**

Ok, so you updated the set description.  Everything I said above is still true, only now your new set is also mathematically meaningful. $\{ f : R \to R \mid f(x) = ax + c \}$ is "the set of functions $f$ from $R$ to $R$ such that $f(x) = ax + c$".

As long as you know what $a$ and $c$ are, this makes sense.  If they remain variables, their description should be included in the set -- e.g., are they real numbers, or complex, etc?  If real, the set should look like $\{f : R \to R \mid f(x) = ax + c \text{ with } a, c \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I created my example too quickly so that it made actually little sense. I hope the new example is better.

Comment: @Johannes You're welcome! Your new set is much more clear, but please read the edit at the bottom of my answer.  We still should technically describe what $a$ and $c$ are in the description.  But yes, it is much better.

Comment: I edited once more, Thanks for the Feedback. So it really does not matter in what order i use "$:$" and "$|$"?

Comment: @Johannes Well, if you are **not** trying to define functions inside of your set description, you can use : or | for "such that", as we saw in my first example.  But if in the description of your set you *are* defining functions, then functions are always defined with :, so you should use | for the "such that" part.  It wouldn't look nice to write $\{f : X \to Y : f(x) = 5 \}$, because the : would be used for two things -- the function definition, and the "such that".  In this case, it's better to write $\{f : X \to Y | f(x) = 5 \}$.